# What Kind Of Test Is This?

Tags: logical-deduction, story

One day, a teacher decided to give unusual multiple test questions to the students. They were all surprised at the questions and none of them got anything correct. Can you help them?

Questions :

> Q1. Which question has a correct answer C)?
>
> A) Q3
>
> B) Q4
>
> C) Q1
>
> D) Q2
>
> Q2. Which question has a correct answer A)?
>
> A) Q4
>
> B) Q2
>
> C) Q3
>
> D) Q1
>
> Q3. Which question has a correct answer D)?
>
> A) Q1
>
> B) Q2
>
> C) Q4
>
> D) Q3
>
> Q4. Which question has a correct answer B)?
>
> A) Q2
>
> B) Q4
>
> C) Q3
>
> D) Q1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answers are

> 1. D
>  2. C
>  3. A
>  4. B

Explanation:

> Q1 has answer as D option whose value is Q2.
>  So Q2 should have its answer as C option whose value is Q3.
>  So Q3 should have answer as option A whose value is Q1. So Q1 should have answer as option D whose value is Q2
>  And that is where we started off.
>  Now Q4 is remaining. The answer to Q4 should be itself as all other questions are covered. So the answer for Q4 should be option B whose value is Q4 itself.

Comment: Can u give explanations for that???

Answer (score 4):

I believe...

> 1. D 
>  2. C 
>  3. A 
>  4. B

Explanation:

> [image: answer]

Comment: Sorry mate but @nikki answered first. Still +1, though :)

Comment: Ah, I'm too late.